# Drawing bar charts from boolean fields:

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have three boolean fields, where their count is shown below:

[image]

I want to draw a bar chart that have

Offline_RetentionByTime with 37528

Offline_RetentionByCount with 29640

Offline_RetentionByCapacity with 3362

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use `apply` [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for creating new `df1` and then [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Offline_RetentionByTime':[True,False,True, False],
                   'Offline_RetentionByCount':[True,False,False,True],
                   'Offline_RetentionByCapacity':[True,True,True, False]})

print (df)
  Offline_RetentionByCapacity Offline_RetentionByCount Offline_RetentionByTime
0                        True                     True                    True
1                        True                    False                   False
2                        True                    False                    True
3                       False                     True                   False

df1 = df.apply(pd.value_counts)
print (df1)
       Offline_RetentionByCapacity  Offline_RetentionByCount  \
True                             3                         2   
False                            1                         2   

       Offline_RetentionByTime  
True                         2  
False                        2  

df1.plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]

If need plot only `True` values select by `loc`:

```
df1.loc[True].plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]